# get results grouped by the same field value in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy

I have 3 MySQL tables: `companies`, `activities`, `association_company_activities`
the `association_company_activitiestable` links `companies` and `activities`, so it has 3 fields: 1 auto increment `ID`, `company_id` as foreing key, and `activity_id` as foreing key.
I have this query:

```
SELECT
    C.id,
    C.label,
    A.name
FROM
    companies C
JOIN activities A JOIN association_company_activities S ON
    C.identifier = S.company_id AND A.identifier = S.activitiy_id
ORDER BY
    C.label
```

As I'm using a python script, the above query corresponds to this:
( I also return the result as a json )

```
def search(args, items):
    args = request.args.to_dict()
    if len(args) > 0:
      for param, value in args.iteritems():
        items = [v for v in items if v.has_key(param) and v[param] == value]
    return items

A = aliased(model.Activity, name='A')
S = aliased(model.AssocCompaniesActivities, name='S')
C = aliased(model.Company, name='C')
activity_area = A.name.label("activities_area")

results = session.query(C.id, C.label, activity_area) \
                 .join(S) \
                 .join(A) \
                 .filter(C.identifier == S.company_id) \
                 .filter(A.identifier == S.activity_id) \
                 .order_by(C.label) \
                 .all()
session.close()
args = request.args.to_dict()
results = search(args, results)
return jsonify({"results": results})
```

This gives me this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "activities_area": "luxury", 
      "id": "company1", 
      "label": "first company"
    }, 
    {
      "activities_area": "banks", 
      "id": "company2", 
      "label": "second company"
    }, 
    {
      "activities_area": "paper", 
      "id": "company2", 
      "label": "second company"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to return the companies with multiple activities only once and get the activity_area as an array like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "activities_area": "luxury", 
      "id": "company1", 
      "label": "first company"
    }, 
    {
      "activities_area": [
           "paper",
           "banks"
      ],
      "id": "company2", 
      "label": "second company"
    }
  ]
}
```

THE MODEL:

```
class Companies(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(String)
    label = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
class Activities(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'activities_area'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class AssocCompaniesActivities(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assoc_companies_activities'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("companies.identifier"), nullable=True)
    activities_area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("activities_area.identifier"), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, company_id , activities_area_id):
        self.company_id = organization_id
        self.activities_area_id = activities_area_id
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Have a look at using the [ORM relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) and [eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading).

Comment: the company table and activity table are not connected with any foreign key. they are linked in the third table association_company_activities

Comment: That's called a [many to many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship). *association_company_activities* would be the "secondary" table.

Comment: Got me. So I don't know how to get the result I want, should I play on the sql query or with the json formatting ...

Comment: This *might* have been asked and answer by [SQLAlchemy with multiple Many to Many Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541262/sqlalchemy-with-multiple-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @metatoaster No that's not it

Comment: @Somar post your three class model definitions (for `Activity`, `AssocCompaniesActivities` and `Company`) or a minimum representation of them in your question will make it clear to us that it isn't identical to what that question/answer I linked.

Comment: @metatoaster Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using the ORM features, it really is similar to that [SQLAlchemy with multiple Many to Many Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541262/sqlalchemy-with-multiple-many-to-many-relationships) and there is a [tutorial on this scenario](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship), however with a subtle difference that you want a class for `AssocCompaniesActivities`.

Preamble for imports and other set up to have your original code work:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

This is the updated class definition:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Companies(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(String)
    label = Column(String)

    activities_area = relationship("Activities", secondary='assoc_companies_activities', back_populates='companies')

    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id 
        self.label = label

class Activities(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'activities_area'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    companies = relationship("Companies", secondary='assoc_companies_activities', back_populates='activities_area')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class AssocCompaniesActivities(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assoc_companies_activities'

    identifier = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("companies.identifier"), nullable=True)
    activities_area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("activities_area.identifier"), nullable=True)
    # Should declare primary key for company_id and activities_area_id,
    # or better yet, just create a simple un-mapped table like in the docs

    def __init__(self, company_id , activities_area_id):
        self.company_id = company_id
        self.activities_area_id = activities_area_id
```

Set up the db, session:

```
session = Session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Finally, add the example data:

```
company1 = Companies(id='company1', label='first company')
company2 = Companies(id='company2', label='second company')
banks_activity = Activities('banks')
luxury_activity = Activities('luxury')
paper_activity = Activities('paper')
session.add(company1)
session.add(company2)
session.add(banks_activity)
session.add(luxury_activity)
session.add(paper_activity)
session.commit()
```

Also the relationships (after committing to have ids for the company and activities)

```
company1_luxury = AssocCompaniesActivities(company1.identifier, luxury_activity.identifier)
company2_banks = AssocCompaniesActivities(company2.identifier, banks_activity.identifier)
company2_paper = AssocCompaniesActivities(company2.identifier, paper_activity.identifier)
session.add(company1_luxury)
session.add(company2_banks)
session.add(company2_paper)
session.commit()
```

With the model updated, we can now do a join query using one of the [relationship loading techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) for eager loading.  This is the part where it is different to other questions, and that there are not that many examples that combine many-to-many relationships with this particular technique to create some for of joined query.  We can achieve what you want using `joinedload`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

companies = session.query(Companies).options(
    joinedload(Companies.activities_area).load_only('name')).all()
```

Which generates this query:

```
SELECT companies.identifier AS companies_identifier, companies.id AS companies_id, companies.label AS companies_label, activities_area_1.identifier AS activities_area_1_identifier, activities_area_1.name AS activities_area_1_name 
FROM companies LEFT OUTER JOIN (assoc_companies_activities AS assoc_companies_activities_1 JOIN activities_area AS activities_area_1 ON activities_area_1.identifier = assoc_companies_activities_1.activities_area_id) ON companies.identifier = assoc_companies_activities_1.company_id
```

Finally, turn the results into the data structure that you desired:

```
print(json.dumps([{
    'id': c.id,
    'label': c.label,
    'activities_area': [a.name for a in c.activities_area]
} for c in companies], indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "company1",
        "label": "first company",
        "activities_area": [
            "luxury"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "company2",
        "label": "second company",
        "activities_area": [
            "banks",
            "paper"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Glad this was of use. That ended up taking up the entire time to write.

Comment: could you check this question out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083092/many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy-with-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-table